# Java: slicing guava multimap

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I have a multimap and I would like to slice it into two different maps using two predicates on keys:

```
A -> keyPred1(K) -> A_1
A -> keyPred2(K) -> A_2
```

At the moment I am doing it getting all values, filtering it using *keyPred1/keyPred2* and rebuilding multimaps from that values again:

```
values1 = a.entries().stream()
                .filter(e -> keyPred1(e.getKey()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

a1 = rebuildMapFromValues(values1);
```

It's ok, but still looks kinda clunky. Is there a way to solve the problem in a smarter way?

Comment: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#filterKeys-com.google.common.collect.Multimap-com.google.common.base.Predicate-

Comment: @JBNizet Qualifies as a 100% hit answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can get live views filtering the multimap by using [`Multimaps.filterKeys(Multimap, Predicate)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#filterKeys-com.google.common.collect.Multimap-com.google.common.base.Predicate-):

```
Multimap<K, V> a1 = Multimaps.filterKeys(a, key -> keyPred1(key));
Multimap<K, V> a2 = Multimaps.filterKeys(a, key -> keyPred2(key));
```

And if you don't want live views then you can copy the filtered views to their own multimap instances. e.g.:

```
Multimap<K, V> a1 = HashMultimap.create(Multimaps.filterKeys(a, key -> keyPred1(key)));
Multimap<K, V> a2 = HashMultimap.create(Multimaps.filterKeys(a, key -> keyPred2(key)));
```